# ping failures with network namespace

Tags: containers

I'm trying understand network namespaces and to that end followed the process in this docker [post](https://docker-k8s-lab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docker/netns.html) to create them. I created a `test` namespace and moved `veth-b` to that namespace, however I can't seem to ping `192.168.3.1` (note that `192.168.2.1` works fine). The interfaces seem to be up, what might the issue be?

```
sudo ip link add veth-a type veth peer name veth-b
```

```bash
$ ifconfig -a

<other_interfaces>
veth-a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::f057:76ff:fec4:5104  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f2:57:76:c4:51:04  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12  bytes 936 (936.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 55  bytes 8117 (7.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```bash
$ sudo ip netns exec test ifconfig -a
lo: flags=8<LOOPBACK>  mtu 65536
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth-b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::58b9:ff:fecc:6fb5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5a:b9:00:cc:6f:b5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 58  bytes 8762 (8.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12  bytes 936 (936.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Ping failure

```bash
$ ping 192.168.3.1
PING 192.168.3.1 (192.168.3.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.3.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2074ms
```

Successful ping

```bash
$ ping 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
^C64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms
```

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.138 metric 600 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.138 metric 600 
192.168.2.0/24 dev veth-a proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

I tried adding a route  `sudo ip route add 192.168.3.0/24 dev veth-a` but that did not help either.

**UPDATE**
After bringing up `lo` in the test network namespace. I don't know why it's complaining about 192.168.2.1 not being reachable. Is the bringing up of `lo` at the right stage as listed in the blog important even through it's not directly pinged?

```
$ ping 192.168.3.1
PING 192.168.3.1 (192.168.3.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Comment: If the veths are configured with IP in different subnets, you need route on *both sides* for "the other" subnet.

Comment: @TomYan thanks, I will give this a try, in the meantime I wonder why it was not needed in the blog post referenced.

Comment: Because `If the veths are configured with IP in different subnets`. In the blog post referenced, both IPs are in `192.168.2.0/24`. By the default a direct route is added automatically for the subnet.